# I have some issue with async approach in react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have some issue with async approach in react-redux. When error occurs in the function its working correctly and dispatch the error, but when the response is ok, it still read error dispatch action. I have used the try catch block. Don't know what the problem in it. Here is the code.

```
export const loginUser = userData => async dispatch => {
    try {
        const res = await axios.post(`/api/user/login`, userData);
        console.log("Res", res)
        const { payload } = res.data.data
        const decoded = jwt_decode(payload);
        console.log("Decode", decoded)
        dispatch({
            type: SET_CURRENT_USER,
            payload: decoded,
            isAuthenticated: true
        });

    } catch (err) {
        console.log('err', err.response)
        dispatch({
            type: GET_ERRORS,
            payload: err.response.data.message
        })
    }
    return
};
```

Comment: What is your error in detail?

Comment: When i hit the api, if there is error from api end point i am storing it in redux for error handling and its working fine, but when the response is ok catch block dispatch function is also running don't know why and it shows err.response is undefined.

Comment: Did you log `err` object instead of `err.response`? It's most likely the error coming from `const { payload } = res.data.data; const decoded = jwt_decode(payload);`